# Not receiving any cookie in response using express-session

Tags: express-session

I have started using express-session. But I am not receiving any cookie in response. Here is my code:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'jdfgghuheghgjbfhfguhrughhdjdjhjghj',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}))

app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body
    //console.log(req.body)
    console.log(email, password)
    const resp = await User.findOne({email,password})
    // console.log(resp)

    if(!resp) {
        // console.log("incorrect details")
        res.json({
            success: false,
            message: "Incorrect details"
        })
        // user login is incorrect 
    } else {
        res.json({
            success: true 
        })
        req.session.user = email
        req.session.save()
        console.log("logging you in")
        //make a session and set user to logged in.
    }
 
})
```

Trying to get the user here:

```
app.get('/api/data', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session)
    res.send('User is =>' + req.session.user)
})
```

I should get a set-cookie in response header in the network tab. Can anyone please tell me where am I missing out?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Cookie in the Chrome DevTools under:

**Application > Storage > Cookies > URL of the express Server**

Reference: [Where is the express-session cookie hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582939/where-is-the-express-session-cookie-hidden)

Also your cookie will inaccessible via Javascript unless you set httpOnly to false. Though i would not recommend it as it is a security measure added for cookies

Answer (score 0):

How do you call your endpoint? Depending on the http request, you may need to send it with `credentials`.

This is the case when you send it via Postman or your frontend runs on a different port.

```
fetch('https://example.com', {
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

Here is a way it works for me on the server side: Maybe that helps you as well.

```
const sessionStore = new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: connection });
const sessionMiddleware = session({
  secret: secret,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: true,
  rolling: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 /* 60min */,
    httpOnly: false,
  },
  store: sessionStore,
});

app.use(sessionMiddleware);
```